# add linefeed when copying Windows 7 files

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

Am running Windows 7 64-bit with 8 GB of memory.

Have a large number of text files that do not have an end_of_line symbol [i.e. LF (\n) or CRLF (\r\n)].

Want to copy the files to a new file to parse and edit.

Using convention Windows "copy," the separate files are concatenated into a single record with only one end_of_line symbol.

How to add a LF or a CRLF to each file before a copy command concatenates the next file to the previous file?

Thanks in advance for advice.

/j

Comment: Windows' copy mechanism copies the files exactly as they are, without changes. Do the files have *nix line endings (`\n`) and you want to convert them to Windows line endings (`\r\n`)? Open the files in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and select **Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows**

Comment: Each file is .html file and opens in a browser. However, there is no \n or \r\n at the end of the file. I do use Notepad++ but I have 25,000 files and opening each to add a \n is not practical. A desirable solution would add \n before concatenating next file. But do not know how to do this.

Comment: Add a line break to the end of each file as I concatenate. Currently, there is no line break in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a folder full of .HTML files, and you want to concatenate them together, but put a blank line between each file as concatenated, you can use something like this code at a command prompt:

```
for %F in (*.html) do type "%F" >>concatenated.html && echo. >>concatenated.html
```

The `echo.` echos a blank line into the file.

If you want to add the string "\r\n" in between instead, you could use something like:

```
for %F in (*.html) do type "%F" >>concatenated.html && echo \r\n >>concatenated.html
```